# MYSQL: Order by search query IN function?

Tags: mysql

I have a query:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE id IN (1,2,3)
```

This returns:

```
ID | Title
1  | Bla
2  | Bla2
3  | Bla3
```

If I change the query to:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE id IN (2,3,1)
```

I still get:

```
ID | Title
1  | Bla
2  | Bla2
3  | Bla3
```

How can I change my query to get:

```
ID | Title
2  | Bla2
3  | Bla3
1  | Bla
```

For the second query? In other words, order the result by the order of the items in the IN query? Is it possible to say something like:

```
ORDER BY ID (2,3,1)
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE id IN (2,3,1)
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(id, '2,3,1')
```

Or you can also order by:

```
ORDER BY FIELD(id, 3,2,1)
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f8637/4).

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `CASE` expression in your `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM products 
WHERE id IN (2,3,1)
order by 
  case id 
    when 2 then 0
    when 3 then 1
    when 1 then 2
    else 3
  end
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bed1a/6)

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `ORDER BY <ASC/DESC>`

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE id IN (1,2,3) order by id desc
```

Comment: @JohnConde Yes Sir, sometimes we can't see the simple stuff

Comment: What if I do this: SELECT * FROM products WHERE id IN (2,3,1) --> this is my concern...

Comment: Yes, but I want to order it by the order I specify in the IN clause?

Comment: My good man I'm afraid that is not what IN is used for. IN is essentially saying is I sure would like all of the rows that contain these values if you could retrieve them for me that would be fantastic. It has absolutely nothing to do with how the records are ordered.

Comment: I understand that. My question is, HOW can I specify the order outright (if at all)?